# Work in an Index with .Selection or a Variable?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have an index of definitions:

Superman - means a really super dude 
Kryptonite - means something superman doesn't like 
etc.

I'd like to loop through each `Paragraph` (since the entries are separated by "Enter") in the index, and underline from the start of it until `-`.

However, I can't figure out how to work with an index. I can update the index (`ActiveDocument.Indexes(1).Update`), but can't figure out how to work with the index. I was thinking something like this:

```
Sub underline_Index_Definitions()
Dim myDoc As Word.Document
Dim numParas&
Dim rng As Word.Range

Set myDoc = ActiveDocument
Debug.Print "You have : " & myDoc.Indexes.Count & " indexes."

numParas = myDoc.Indexes(1).Paragraphs.Count
For Each par In Indexes(1)
    'Select the text from the start, until a dash

    ' blah blah blah
Next par

End With

End Sub
```

But of course, it errors out at the `numParas` line since I can't do that.  I also can't do `myDoc.Indexes(1).Select // With Selection ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
numParas = myDoc.Indexes(1).Range.Paragraphs.Count
```

You'll get this often in Word - when something that looks "text-like" doesn't give you Paragarphs, Words, etc. see if that "something" has a Range object (often it does).

Note that the Index.Range include three extra Paragraphs that you probably won't recognize and will need to handle in a loop.

Comment: Thanks! The `.Range` in between was what I was missing. Much appreciated!